# Knowing the Arduino memory capacity

Tags: c

I am using Arduino uno. My data is storing into EEPROM whenever i run my program, it will store multiple data depend on the loop. For my program it calculate 10 sample in 0.1 sec, so 100 sample in 1 sec. How can i know how much memory i can run?

I have added this code to my program it display 895.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v; 
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval); 
}
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(freeRam());}
void loop(){}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `freeRam()` method you are suggesting calculates the "space" between the `heap` and the `stack`, thus it returns the free `SRAM`.

There is no way to calculate free remaining `EEPROM` (if that is what you are asking), since it just contains some arbitrary data at arbitrary locations. Get the `EEPROM` capacity from the device data sheet and make sure to write within its boundaries.

Comment: Writing to EEPROM is relatively slow. Check EEPROM speed (older and new EEPROM differs greatly, some only do page write, some do byte write) and your sample size (number of byte to write) to see if 10 sets of sample in 0.1 sec is ok.

Comment: @JohnWilliams: ATMEGA internal EEPROM is indeed very slow. One erase/write operation takes easily 3ms. Thus, writing 10 values every 100ms (OPs requirement) you spend >30ms only storing the data. This is assuming that one value only has 1 Byte width.

Comment: I wonder if it is against rules to response with 'not asked' info, when the info is important for success of the original poster. EEPROM in UNO and Mega2560 is 100,000 times write life (less than 1 day in this case), as per Arduino web link to factory data sheet, page 1 http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc8161.pdf  People actually test it to death in http://hackaday.com/2011/05/16/destroying-an-arduinos-eeprom/  EEPROM was designed to store in frequent changing data, like calibration data, last power down and restore, etc